# Error calling method

Tags: java, methods, error-handling

I am working on a class assignment to get a coin to flip and record the amounts of times it lands on heads or tails. I am pretty sure most of this is right but the part that is throwing me off, is calling the method "coinFlip".  when I try to call it in the counter class, I get the error message "coinFlip cannot be resolved to a type" I can't seem to figure out how to fix it, or grasp an understanding as to why I am getting that message.  Any help is appreciated, thanks ahead of time.

```
package coinProject;

public class GenericCoin {

    public class coinFlip{
        private int heads = 0;
        private int sideUp; //used to record which side the coin lands on

        public coinFlip(){
            flip();
        }

        public void flip(){
            sideUp = (int) (Math.random() * 2);//used to keep random number under 2
        }

        public boolean headFlip(){
            return (sideUp == heads);
        }

        public String toString(){//limits to only two print options, heads or tails
            return (sideUp == heads) ? "Heads" : "Tails";
        }
    }

}
```

================================================================================

```
package coinProject;



public class counter {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final int flip = 50;
        int headFlips = 0 , tailFlips = 0;

        coinFlip coin = new coinFlip();


        for(int i = 1; i <= flip; i++){
            coin.flip();

            if(coin.headFlip()){
                headFlips ++;
            }
            else{
                tailFlips ++;
            }

            System.out.println(coin.toString());
        }

        System.out.println();//creates gaps after flips
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("----- Flipped: " + flip);
        System.out.println("----- Heads: " + headFlips);
        System.out.println("----- Tails: " + tailFlips);


    }

}
```

Comment: Java coding style prefers to have classes and packages names starting with a capital.
Also: any specific reason to have `coinFlip` an inner class of `GenericCoin`?

Comment: coinFlip isn't a method, it's an inner class.

Comment: It was kind of an accident, I added a class and started working after creating a project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `coinFlip` as an inner class so you need an instance of `GenericCoin` before you can instantiate a `coinFlip'. So you need:

```
GenericCoin.coinFlip coin = new GenericCoin().new coinFlip();
```

Comment: An inner **non static** class to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Oracle tutorial on nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html): you need to define your `coinFlip` class as `public static class coinFlip` instead of `public class coinFlip`, the latter needing an instance of the enclosing class, as @user2341963 mentionned.